# Wordpress the_content loop issue

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Currently I'm creating a product review site with Wordpress for tafe/college. Everything is going to plan except for one issue - on the single post page.

I'm getting the title, the date submitted, the post image. But for some bizarre reason my sidebar has vanished and the content is gone as well. I'm guessing either I've missed out a good portion of php code somewhere.

I actually have a test site where the content is located so u can get a better look: www.sbmwebdesign.com (It's just a site used for tafe work, will expire in a short time).

My code is below:

```
<?php 
get_header();
?>

<div class="title_wrapper container">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="span6">
                            <h1><?php /* post title */ the_title() ;?></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="breadcrumbs">
                            <strong><a href="index.html">Home</a> / <a href="blog-right-sidebar.html">Reviews</a>  / <?php /* post title */ the_title() ;?></strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container blog blog-ind">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span8">
                        <div class="blog-post">
                            <div class="blog-image">
                                <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/img/defaults/817x320.jpg" class="attachment-817x320 wp-post-image" alt="2" height="320" width="817"></a>
                                <div class="blog-date">
                                    <span class="date"><?php 
    // Date published (Returns a formatted date string)
        the_time('l jS F');?></span>
                                    <!-- <div class="plove"><a href="#" class="heart-love" id="heart-love-499" title="Love this"><span class="heart-love-count"><span class="icon-heart"></span>54</span></a></div> -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog-rating">
                                    <div class="overall-score">
                                        <div class="rating r-45"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- blog-rating -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- blog-image -->
                            <div class="">
                                <h2><?php /* post title */ the_title() ;?></h2>
                            </div>
                            <!-- blog-content -->
                            <div class="blog-info">
                                <!--<div class="post-pinfo">
                                    <span class="icon-user"></span> <a data-original-title="View all posts by admin" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#">admin</a> &nbsp;
                                    <span class="icon-comment"></span>  <a data-original-title="3 Comments" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip">
                                    3 Comments</a> &nbsp;
                                    <span class="icon-tags"></span><a href="#"> Adventure,  </a>  <a href="#"> RPG,  </a>  <a href="#"> Shooter,  </a>  <a href="#"> Strategy,  </a> 
                                </div>-->
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.blog-info -->
                            <!-- <?php get_review() ;?> -->
                            <div class="blog-content">
                                <p><?php $content = get_the_content(); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.blog-content -->
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.blog-post -->
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="block-divider"></div>
                    </div> 

                    <?php 
get_sidebar();
?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            get_footer();
            ?>

<!-- JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.pack.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login-with-ajax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/global.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/imagescale.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login-with-ajax.source.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transit.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/greensock.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/layerslider.transitions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery("#layerslider").layerSlider({
                pauseOnHover: false,
                autoPlayVideos: false,
                skinsPath: './layerslider/skins/',
                responsive : true,
                responsiveUnder : 1200,
                layersContainer : 1200,
                skin_name: 'fullwidth',
                navStartStop: false
            });
        </script>

       <!-- End JavaScript -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Btw to get to the page in question just click on the post shown in the index page.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your browser page source. I see `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_review()`

*(That's the first thing to always do; check your browser source).*

**You can't** use `<!--` and `-->` HTML comments to comment out or deactivate a  PHP call.

Use instead

`<?php /* get_review() ; */?>`

or

`<?php // get_review() ;?>`

All PHP after that undefined function failure won't execute, so none of the end of post and/or sidebar HTML appears, so the rest of the page doesn't appear.

**You can** use `<!--` and `-->` to add a comment like this

`<!-- comment here about what is going on -->`

by itself without it surrounding any PHP code.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Commenting_Code

Comment: Fixed Mark! Used the wrong code to try and comment that part out. Thanks.

Problem is though that that get_review part was supposed to grab some code belonging to a review.php file I made up to show in the content. Just wasn't working for some reason so I wanted to take it out.